# which is a better way of making symbian applications?

Tags: qt, java-me, mobile, symbian

I have read it on the official website that there are several ways in which we can make applications that run on the Symbian OS.

These include development in QT and J2ME.  I wanted to know which between this would be a better way of developing applications for the Symbian platform and why ?

I am a fairly new developer in this field although i have developed several Android applications in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT is the native framework for Symbian. The installers have a SIS and SISX file extension, and they can use extended capabilities,  within Nokia's Symbian (S60v3, v5, S40, and Symbian^3). Like **better handling** of the accelerometer/gyroscope and camera functions, etc.

On the other hand, if you are targeting many platforms (other than Symbian too),along with other phone OS's, you should go for J2ME.

You will be losing some advanced functionality, in exchange for better portability and compatiblity.

Comment: i am just going to be focusing on nokia mobile devices. That is the system 40 series and the symbian series. For this is J2ME enough, or would it have problems that i would run on some nokia devices and not on the others?

Comment: Yes, it is quite sufficient. If you are targeting S40, J2ME is definitely the one for you.

Comment: Also if i am developing in j2me which would be the best IDE? There is this ide that sun provides on its own and then there is netbeans. which is better?

Comment: S40 is not a Symbian platform, J2ME or web-apps is the only choice. Eclipse and Netbeans both support j2me development.

Comment: Exactly what i was saying! @user590849:Netbeans for me! But hey, its all personal preference...

Answer (score 2):

I dont agree with anirudh4444.

Symbian C++ is the native programming language for Symbian and not Qt. [[1](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Series_40_web_apps/)]

Since you have mentioned that you want to target S40 and if you want to develop web based application, you have to check [this](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Series_40_web_apps/).